# Weblogic WebService client dependencies

Tags: web-services, dependencies, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper, jax-rpc

I would like to ask which would be the correct jar files needed to a functional ws client to an authenticated weblogic JAX-RPC.
 
Situation:
I created the same WS client on Jdeveloper and on OEPE. When I run in the IDE, my client only works on Jdeveloper. Then I generated a Jar file from Jdeveloper and the same error from OEPE ocurrs when I run that jar. 
I suppose this happens because there are some libs missing. I really need help!
 After putting many libs on the classpath, this is the mistake:

> "Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Failed to
>   parse WSDL htp://url?WSDL weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Failed to
>   read wsdl file from url due to -- java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect
>           at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.throwServiceException(ServiceImpl.java:185)
>           at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.loadWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:492)
>           at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:126)
>           at br.com.scopus.teste.ServicoAssinaturaImplService_Impl.(ServicoAssinaturaImplService_Impl.java:21)
>           at br.com.scopus.teste.Client.main(Client.java:26) Caused by: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Failed to read wsdl file from url d
>   ue to -- java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.getDocument(WsdlReader.java:313)
>           at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlDefinitionsImpl.parse(WsdlDefinitions
>   Impl.java:432)
>           at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlDefinitionsImpl.parse(WsdlDefinitions
>   Impl.java:417)
>           at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:81)
>           at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:68)
>           at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.loadWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:
>   483)
>           ... 3 more"

**Maybe Important information:**

These are the jar I am using: wlfullclient.jar wsclient.jar adf-config.xml weblogic.jar wseeclient.jar wsclient_extended.jar glassfish.jaxws.rt_1.2.0.0_2-1-5.jar 
Weblogic version: 10.3.5
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a library issue.
You are getting "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". So the web service stack managed to perform the call to the WSDL URL but couldn't get through. One reason could be that your URL is incorrect, referring the incorrect interface (localhost rather than actual hostname or vice versa) or anything else.

Try to copy-paste the URL it is telling you it can't access in a web-browser and you should see the same problem.